# in/at the company

Tags: prepositions

I have made the examples below.

(1) As a project manager, I go to my clients' companies and talk about business projects with them most of the time. Today, my employer tells me that I will get a promotion soon. In my new position, I will always work **in/at** the company.

(2) Jack has the most work experience **at/in** my company.

I am not sure which preposition is correct.

Answer (score 1):

to work **for** a/the company
to have the most experience of anyone **in** the company
to **be at** the company [for the day or for work or for whatever reason]

to be at = location, geographical or spatially

at home
at work
at school

Answer (score 0):

I work at a company (insert company name) in a capacity that is important.
I work in a certain capacity at my company.
at: general
in: specific

Comment: The trouble with your "rule" in the last four words is _I work in banking_ - even more general. The fact is that English speakers say "work at [a company]" more often than they say "work in [a company]" (between 2:1 and 4:1, judging from some searches in the iWeb corpus), but there is no useful rule to account for this: it's an unpredictable aspect of how we use words

Answer (score 0):

(1) *I will always work at the company.* You don't have to travel outside, "in the company" typically means you are a member/employee of the company.

(2) Generally you use "in". Unless say Jack is a visitor and you want to find out who is the tallest currently at the company (building).